# ASP.Net MVC - Desenhar em arquivo PDF?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou criando um sistema em `Asp.Net MVC` e preciso criar um esquema para que o usuário desenhe sua assinatura em um arquivo.pdf que eh correspondente a um contrato e estou procurando uma forma de fazer isso mas ainda não encontrei.

Vi que com o iTextSharp eh possível desenhar formas geométricas, mas não encontrei como fazer isso de forma livre como um lápis do Paint Brush por exemplo.

Dei uma olhada na SDK da Adobe e Foxit mas tbm não encontrei uma maneira de fazer isso, apesar de na documentação informar que eh possível.

Como fazer isso ?